# Using Kate with Simple Build Tool (SBT)

Tags: scala, plugins, editor, sbt, kate

Hello I am working with the Kate editor based on the lack of other good tools for Scala development, I am also using IntelliJ however it still has some bugs, and are slow enough to make me impatient.

I have just startet using both Kate and SBT, and in that regard I have a little challenge I hope there is an answer for out there on "The Internet".

I am using the standard "Build plugin" in Kate and has changed the commands from make to sbt. This works fine, and I am also getting a error report when the sbt fails during compile time. However I really wish to know if it is possible to integrate the compile errors into Kate such that it would be shown under "Errors and Warnings" instead of just in the output tab, where I have to do a manual search for the compile errors.

Im guessing that it has something to do with the format of the output, if that is the case maybe it is "just" a smaller adjustment I need to make to the parsing language.

Comment: If you're using IDEA + SBT, what gap remains? This is how I work, editing in IDEA and building in SBT. I agree IDEA's Scala compilation is usually very slow while SBT in its interactive or continuous-build modes is about a good as it gets (modulo its conservative dependency calculation).

Comment: Thats a good idea, I think I will use that on my windows machine. On the other side I would still like a light-weight development environment for my linux machine, thats why I really would like to know if there is something to be done with kate to integrate with sbt, or maybe another editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clearify the status of the question.

I have not been able to find anything which can solve this problem, so I have decided to use IntelliJ Community Edition with Scala as only active plugin, in that way IntelliJ can start in about 35 seconds cold, and 20 seconds when "warmed" up, this is supported by the SBT tool underneath.
Currently it seems like the best solution.